# Multiple alertviews in a single view?

Tags: iphone

I have an Iphone application in which when i am pressing a button it shows an alertview to chose the background.whichever background user is chosing will be played as the background of the audio clips.But now i need to add another alert before i am showing this alert for giving some warning.after that only i need to pop the second one.but i was done that chosing alert in the didappear of that viewcontroller and set it as a Uialertview delegate.and on the button actions i was doing different actions.Can anybody help me on achieving this?

```
proAlertView *loginav1=[[proAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"Choose a Background to play with this program?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Field",@"Beach", @"Stars",nil];
[loginav1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.129 green:0.129 blue:0.129 alpha:1.0] withStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.625 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.8 alpha:0.8]];




[loginav1 show];
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
// the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons




if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    //[self play];
    //moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    if(actionSheet.tag==123)
    {
        [self backButtonPressed];
    }




}
else if (buttonIndex == 1)
{

     videoFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video-track" ofType:@"mp4"];
    [self play];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;



}
```

how can i include another alert before this is my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize first Alertview

```
UIAlertView *al1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Warning Msg!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
al1.tag=1;
al1.delegate=self;
[al1 show];
```

Implement Delegate method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(alertView.tag==1){
        // implement button events for first Alertview
        if(buttonIndex==1){
            //First button clicked of first Alertview
            UIAlertView *al2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose BG" message:@"Choose BG?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
            al2.tag=2;
            al2.delegate=self;
            [al2 show];
        }

    }

    if(alertView.tag==2){
        // implement button events for second Alertview
        if(buttonIndex==1){
            // First button clicked second Alertview.
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Class header

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>{

}
```

Hope this will fulfill your need !

Comment: hi I was clearly state that i need to give a simple warning message before my chosing of bg msg.What you r doing is after chosng bg u r going for the another msg.that is not i want sorry man

Comment: But Man you can switch that Alert views! Use "al1" for warning and when user press "Ok" button of "al1", open "al2" to choose BG sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, first display warning message in alertview and when user click OK in alertview then in alertview delegate method write code to display second alertview where user can choose background.

Comment: Now i am handling The chosing alert in delegate with 3 buttons.how can i include those actions in to to the ok button action of warning